# AWS Codepipeline: grab credentials for use in build step?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-codepipeline

I have an AWS Code Pipeline whose build step uses the AWS CLI, so of course it needs AWS credentials to work.

I don't see how to do this ... the 'source stage' checks out from github and therefore has the source artifact as its output artifact.

I wound up just committing the credentials into the branch I'm building from (currently unencrypted, though I can of course encrypt them if this workaround has to go into production) ... and this works.

Isn't there some way to do this "correctly" without getting the credentials from that branch?

Comment: CodeBuild should automatically allow you to use AWS CLI, without needing to check in creds in repository. Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-versions. The access key and secret should be available to you within the build context.

Answer (score 1):

In the build action, if you are using CodeBuild project, You need to attach custom policies to CodeBuild service role.  So, when you use  AWS CLI  goes through the credentials providers in order and will fetch temporary credentials for that role.
This way you don't  have to commit sensitive environment configuration in your repo.